# C++ function errors

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++ and I've been trying to use functions and for a while. I was using them just fine but when I wrote this recent code my compiler (Visual Studio) keeps giving me errors, I can't tell if it is just something small I did that I'm not noticing or how I'm using the function.

I've been looking at it for a while and I'm just getting frustrated so I went and made a simpler code and the same thing happened.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int swordString();

int main()
{
    int age;
    int yearsleft;

    cout << "How old are you?" << endl;
    cin >> age;

    yearsleft = swordString(age);

    cout << "You have " << yearsleft << " years left to live!" << endl;

    return 0;
}

int swordString(int a)
{
    int r;
    r = 100 - a;
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Please update your post to include the errors you're getting.

Comment: Well, maybe tell us what the errors are for starters?

Comment: You need to put some detail about the error in your title and for sure in your question.

Comment: `I dont really know how this site works`. Try [reviewing the help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find out how to ask a question with the right details.

Comment: to everyone saying to provide the error i already fixed the issue but anyways the error was:    Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2660 'swordString': function does not take 1 arguments combat p 15

Comment: Maybe next time you try to fix it first and only then post it to SO?

Comment: @FabulousGamer I think you got a lot of flak for this question, but I hope you understand that you did a great thing by at least providing a solid [mcve], which I feel is to be commended.  Please don't forget to click the check mark next to the correct solution.  That's very important, to show you "prove" your question was appropriately answered.

Answer (score 3):

Change your function prototype from:

```
int swordString();
```

to

```
int swordString(int a);
```

Comment: I believe he mistook the `function` start with the top call of said function and noticed it.

Comment: @FabulousGamer If you already had this in then your code would have [been fine](http://ideone.com/LSQKGD)

Answer (score 2):

Prototyping is the same as  declaring a function before it is used and this  enables the complier to provide stronger type checking.

so you are telling your compiler...

*Hey I will need this*

```
int swordString();
```

but then later in the code you are telling:

*hey resolve this:*

```
int a = swordString(age);
```

so what are you expecting from the compiler to do?

it will complain....

you must carefully implement the method according to what you prototyped...